# Number theory proof: Let $w=a+\sqrt{3}\cdot b$ where $w\neq 0$. Let $|N(w)| = 3^{a}\cdot k$, where $3\nmid k$...

Tags: number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, divisibility

Let $w$ be an extended integer (of the form $a+b\sqrt{3}$) with $w\neq 0$. Let $|N(w)| = 3^{a}\cdot k$, where $3\nmid k$ (See hw 4). Prove that there exists am extended integer $z$ such that $w = (\sqrt{3})^a\cdot z$ and $|N(z)| = k$.

[Note- In the aforementioned hw 4, we proved the following statement: Suppose $n$ is a positive integer. Prove that there are unique integers $a\geq 0$ and $k>0$ such that $n = 3^{a}\cdot k$ and $k$ is not divisible by $3$.]

I'm trying to proceed by induction.

For the base case, we take the case where $w = 1$. We observe that for this to be true, $a=0$ and $z=1$, so $1 = \sqrt{3}^{0}\cdot 1 = 1$. If this is true then

$|N(w)| = |N(1)| = 3^{0} \cdot k = 3^{0} \cdot 1 = 1$

(since there are no extended integers with norm equal to $-1$). We now have $k = 1$ and $z = 1$, we see that $|N(z)| = |N(1)| = 1 = k$. Hence the base case is complete.

Now we suppose for induction that we have established existence for all $w$ such that $1\leq w\leq m$ and we want to show that we can write $m+1$ in the required form. We are now left with two cases: either $m+1$ is divisible by $3$ or it is not. In the case where it is not divisible by $3$, we can just say that $a = 0$ and $z = m+1$.

We now suppose that $m+1$ is divisible by $3$. Since we know that $\sqrt{3}\mid 3$ and $3\mid m+1$, then we can say $\sqrt{3}\mid m+1$. We can now say $m+1 = \sqrt{3}w$ for an $w$ such that $1\leq w\leq m$. However, we already stated that this was true in the induction hypothesis so we can write $w = \sqrt{3}^a\cdot z$ where $a\geq 0$, $z$ is an extended integer, and $z$ is not divisible by $3$ and therefore not divisible by $\sqrt{3}$ (I'm not sure if this is entirely true). We then have

$m+1 = \sqrt{3}w = \sqrt{3}\cdot(\sqrt{3}^a\cdot z) = \sqrt{3}^{a+1}\cdot z$

and since we still have $a+1>0$ and $z$ is not divisible by $\sqrt{3}$ we have written $m+1$ in the required form. This completes induction.

$\textbf{Okay, so there are a few things I'm not sure if I can say.}$

$\textbf{1. I'm not sure if I can say that $a\geq 0$ since it isn't explicitly stated in the problem}$

$\textbf{2. I'm not sure if $3\nmid z$ or $\sqrt{3}\nmid z$}$

Any advice on how to clean up this proof or work it out in a better way would be greatly appreciated.